# drag bookmarklet ie

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, hyperlink, bookmarklet

Apparently, In IE You can NOT drag a javascript link (bookmarklet) to your bookmarks bar, but [normal links](http://google.com) work just fine.

Is there any workaround that will enable this? I don't want the users to have to right click and add it to their favorites?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: nope.

Long answer:
Only "normal" links are allowed to be programmatically added to your favorites or bookmark bar.

From the documentation:

> Calling the AddFavorite method with a file:// or javascript: URL returns a Permission Denied error .

I've made a small test here: (Internet Explorer only) http://jsfiddle.net/PM5544/hV2yC/ to show it and the documentation is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535926(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197035(v=vs.85).aspx